# jQuery form validation messages

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I have a jsfiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/ac41qxsw/2/

It's a simple form with validation.

If the fields are empty I would like to didsplay an error message by adding a p tag with a message.

The alerts fire when the fields are empty but I can't add the p tags with messages

```
        $('#btn').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

            if(verfiyFields()){
                alert('passed');
            }else{
                alert('failed');
            }    

        })


        function verfiyFields(){
            var flag = true;

            if($('#name').val().length == 0 ){
                $(this).parent().append('<p>Please complete name</p>');
                alert('name');
                flag = false;
            }
            if($('#number').val().length == 0 ){
                $(this).parent().append('<p>Please complete number</p>');
                alert('number');
                flag = false;
            }

            return flag;
        }
```

Comment: Please debug yourself first: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated code:

```
var verfiyFields;
$(function(){
$('#btn').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();

if(verfiyFields()){
    alert('passed');
}else{
    alert('failed');
}    

})
verfiyFields = function (){
var flag = true;

if($('#name').val().length == 0 ){
    $('#name').parent().append('<p>Please complete name</p>');
    flag = false;
}
if($('#number').val().length == 0 ){
    $('#number').parent().append('<p>Please complete number</p>');
    flag = false;
}

return flag;
}
});
```

#### Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/ac41qxsw/7/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using $(this).parent() in the verificiation function specify the name of the element.

In this case $(this) is referring to the $("#btn") element instead of the $("#name") or $("#number") field because you called the method in the click event of $("#btn").